# Cards containing personal information which revolve around a device by the name of

Tags: single-word-requests

In one of the episodes of "Person of Interest" a sci-fi TV show currently popular, one of the main characters "Harold Finch" uses a quote, something similar to the following combination of words:

"Don't worry, we have more names in our ...".

The part with the dots is an unusual word which I immediately looked up (I forgot the exact name of the device). The device mentioned was something that was used post second world war and no longer popular, it contained cards with personal information of whomever, which you could slide over the device one by one. In some sense it could be seen as a personal phone book sort of thing, except more geared towards just information like address, zip/postal code, city, etc. What is the name of such a device?

I hope this description is not too vague. (I'm also uncertain about the tagging, so feel free to edit that.)

Comment: Hey, no fair! Am I the only one here who got thrown off by "no longer popular? Regardless, +1 across the board.

Comment: @PapaPoule I was just citing the source I found when I looked up the word. In retrospect that appears to be untrue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rolodex!

Per Google Dictionary:

> a desktop card index used to record names, addresses, and telephone numbers, in the form of a rotating spindle or a small tray to which removable cards are attached.
>
> informal:
> a person's list of business contacts and friends.

[image]

Comment: .... usually sitting next to a dial desk phone or typewriter.  Ahhhhh, the old days.

Comment: @user116032  Quite so! For me the good old days meant a Filofax. I couldn't get the hang of schlepping the Rolo-thingy around with me.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for Rolodex